# Return <ClassName>.class instead of simply <ClassName> in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to use reflections to decide on runtime which method needs to be called. 
I have used the below piece of code to implement the same:

```
    private Method getSetterMethod(Object tempVar, Object genericDTO, String field) {
        Method getterMethod1 = null;

        if(tempVar instanceof String)
            getterMethod1 = genericDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1), String.class);
        else if(tempVar instanceof Integer)
            getterMethod1 = genericDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1), Integer.class);
        else if(tempVar instanceof String[])
            getterMethod1 = genericDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1), String[].class);
        else if(tempVar instanceof Boolean)
            getterMethod1 = genericDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1), Boolean.class);

        return getterMethod1;

    }
}
```

The decision is made based on tempVar. I wanted to be able to return String.class directly from tempVar so that I can avoid multiple if-else-if blocks. 
Right now tempVar.getClass() returns only String. Is there a method that outputs something like String.class instead of simply String.

Comment: Please add a bit more code. This example is lacking a bit.

Comment: If tempVar is a String, then `tempVar.getClass()` returns `Class<String>`.

Comment: did you try tempVar.getClass()?

Comment: I did try tempVar.getClass(). However, it's output is String and I specifically need String.class as the output.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Added the entire method.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need `<some_class>.class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
if (!Arrays.asList(String.class,String[].class, Boolean.class, Integer.class).contains(tempVar.getClass())){
    return null;
} 
return genericDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1), tempVar.getClass());
```